# How to Pass a GUID to ExceptionFilter for Each Error that Occurs?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an API as follows(Mock API), where I am pushing the exception in the catch block to a Central logging Portal. Again in the Exception Filter I am phrasing the Exception Message & throwing the message to User.

```
 [customeFilter]
    Public asyc Task<IactionResult> DoTask()
    {
    try
    {
    //sample Code
    }
    
    catch(exception ex)
    {
    _log.LogError(ex);
    }


public class customeFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
 HttpStatusCode? httpErrorCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            if (context.Exception is DivideByZeroException dvd)
            {
                context.Result = new ObjectResult(dvd.Data)
                {
                    StatusCode = (int?)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                    Value = "There is an issue with the data"
                };
                context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
}
}
```

Issue: I want to keep the same Guid to both systems, i.e., to the central Logging & to the User via Exception Filter. I tried some approach to pass the information to Exception Filter, but didn't have any success with that. Even tried to find any unique identifier in the Exception object, but didn't find any.

Note:

1. I have a thought about Pushing the exception Log in the Exception Filter instead of Catch block. But I don't want to go with Static Class/Methods.

Comment: You can wrap another Exception around, where you set the Guid and the message. Then check in the Filter for InnerException of context.Exception.

Comment: In that case how to push the Custom Exception to the Filter?

Comment: throw newException;

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to track your user and his/her corresponding exception?
If you wan't my opinion, you don't need to generate a guid for this goal. You can use _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier
Just inject your IHttpContextAccessor inside the filter and use TraceIdentifier.
For more clarification you can set that trace identifier in header of response you can do something like this:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public CustomFilterAttribute(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
      HttpStatusCode? httpErrorCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        if (context.Exception?.InnerException is DivideByZeroException dvd)
        {
            string uid = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
            //logger.log(uid + exception).
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("tracking-uid", uid);
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(dvd.Data)
            {
                StatusCode = (int?)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Value = "There is an issue with the data"
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: In my current context, i want to pass the same Guid across 2 systems. not the user . So that if a user finds a Guid in response he/she should be able to use the Guid to search in the Logging system

Comment: Ok I see. So you can ignore the line that is sending the TraceIdentifier to user header response and you can use TraceIdentifier for using in your other systems.
If you have any further questions I can help you again dear.